# How to plot a box plot in R for outlier detection for a huge number of rows?

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

[image: Added screenshot of error]I have a dataset which has a huge number of rows. I want to plot the boxplot of a single feature, but the simple boxplot() command in R gives me an error.

I am working on a dataset with more than 200,000 rows. The head looks like this:

year

month

day

n_impacted

2013    Jan Tue 4
2013    Jan Mon 4
2013    Jan Sat 5
2013    Jan Wed 4
2013    Jan Fri 4
2013    Jan Sat 5

boxplot(na_omit_noguns$n_impacted)

Error in plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, log = log, yaxs = pars$yaxs) : need finite 'ylim' values

I should be able to plot the box plot with the outliers showing up.

Comment: Your example is not giving any error.  Please post an example that shows the error

Comment: Hi @akrun thanks for having a look. I have added a screenshot of the error that I see.

Comment: If you have `Inf` or `-Inf`, try`i1 <- is.finite(na_omit_noguns$n_impacted); boxplot(na_omit_noguns$n_impacted[i1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurred due to `Inf` or `-Inf` values.  It can be corrected by removing those elements by subsetting only the finite values (with `is.finite`)

```
i1 <- is.finite(na_omit_noguns$n_impacted)
boxplot(na_omit_noguns$n_impacted[i1])
```